# Aptana Studio 3 Menu Bar in OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, python, macos, aptana, osx-mavericks

Well I know other people are having the same problem, and I did see a similar question already on Stack Overflow, but I'm still having problems.

I updated the latest JRE (prompted to as soon as I opened Aptana) and now when I run Aptana, the menu bar is gone and replaced with the menu bar of the last application window I had open (Right now, Chrome). The solution I found was to install the newest fix of Aptana, but the instructions said to update it by navigating through the very menu bar that isn't appearing. Talk about pulling my hair out. Obviously, I could do a complete reinstall of the app but I want to avoid this. I've spent a lot of time making personal themes for syntax.

As the title states, I'm running Mavericks OS.

So my question is, is there an alternative to install this update without having to do a full reinstall of Aptana?

Comment: I suggest using the shortcut to show key assist (on Windows its `Ctrl + Shift + L`) to bring up the list of available key shortcuts. From here, looks for the 'Quick Access' shortcut (`Ctrl + 3` on Windows). In this window you can type or browse for whatever command you want including the update and install commands. Sorry I don't have Mac shortcuts for you.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was just about to try your suggestion and then the menu bar displayed. I guess it works sometimes. Anyway it stayed long enough for me to install the new update. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

The latest Aptana Studio 3.4.3 RC build contains support for Mavericks. You could update using the update site http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/rc/.

Comment: The irony here is that you need the menu to use those updates from that link